# PHP/Mysql: Date lower than today

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my database I have a field that's named: `expires_in` and that has values such as `2015-05-01` (YYYY-MM-DD), I need to do a search on this field (from PHP) and get back

a) dates that are lower than today (eg yesterday or x days ago)
b) dates that are greater than today but less than 2 weeks from today

I have a feeling that if I know `a` then `b` won't be hard...

Comment: Why not do this in the query?

Comment: Google "mysql date/time functions"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should query the MySQL database as follows:

A) `SELECT * FROM table WHERE expires_in < CURDATE()`

B) `SELECT * FROM table WHERE expires_in > CURDATE() AND expires_in < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)`

More information about MySQL time/date functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html